# I try to parse my JSON into my Java with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, retrofit

I tried someone's tutorial to parse JSON in Java using retrofit.

I change the url in the tutorial with mine http://umkmkabupatenmalang.xyz/api/config/ . But when I try to run it on Android, I get an error like this

[image]

this is my MainActivity.java

```
import ... 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> data;
    private DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view();
    }

    private void view(){
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
    }

    private void loadJSON(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://umkmkabupatenmalang.xyz/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));
                adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my json that i want to parse

[image]

can someone explain to me whats the error mean, and give a solution?

this is my JSONResponse

```
import com.example.skripsi.model.AndroidVersion;

public class JSONResponse {
    private AndroidVersion[] android;

    public AndroidVersion[] getAndroid() {
        return android;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's on MainActivity.java line 57? That is where your issue as reported by the runtime...

Comment: What is the JSONResponse class?

Comment: you can see above,I have added my JSONResponse

Comment: this is on line 57 - >  data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getAndroid()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `JSONResponse` class, you should also provide a setter.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.example.skripsi.model.AndroidVersion;

public class JSONResponse {
    @SerializedName("data")
    private AndroidVersion[] android;

    public AndroidVersion[] getAndroid() {
        return android;
    }

    public setAndroid(AndroidVersion[] androids){
        this.android = androids;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website to convert your JSON to java classes in the future
[Convert JSON into java classes](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)